# google api call to big query wont give refresh token using c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, token, refresh

I have read and read and played with this code inside out and I still cant work out how to get the refresh token. This in c#

I have tried different combo of access_type, prompt and approval_prompt params.
I keep revoking access by my user to the app, so when the auth code is being requested it does ask for myself to approve the app to be able to access.

I just want to get the refresh token so i can store it and keep refreshing.

here is the code below. I have removed the parts to get the auth code, but if it is needed i can add in. I wonder if anyone can simply spot something simply wrong.

```
        string GetJsonFromAPICall(string p_url,string p_post_data, string p_b64_id_secret)
            {
                //string C_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
                string l_auth_string = "Basic " + p_b64_id_secret;
    
                print("p_post_data = ", p_url + "?"+p_post_data);
                print("Authorization", l_auth_string);
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(p_url) as HttpWebRequest;
    
                string postData = p_post_data;// "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + p_auth_code + "&redirect_uri=" + p_redirect_url;
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", l_auth_string);
                
    
    
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    
                print("pos 20 in GetJsonFromAPICall");
                print("length ", data.Length.ToString());
    
                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    
                return responseString;
            }    

 

string getAccessToken(string p_b64_id_secret, string p_auth_code, string p_redirect_url)
                {
                    //string l_url = "client_id="+ p_C_GBQ_ONLINE_APP_APP_CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret="+ p_C_GBQ_ONLINE_APP_APP_CLIENT_SECRET + "access_type=offline&prompt=consent&grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + p_auth_code + "&redirect_uri=" + p_redirect_url;
                    string l_params = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + p_auth_code + "&redirect_uri=" + p_redirect_url;
                    l_params += "&access_type=offline";
                    l_params += "&prompt=consent";
                    l_params += "&approval_prompt=force";
        
                    //return GetJsonFromAPICall("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", l_params, p_b64_id_secret);
                    return GetJsonFromAPICall("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", l_params, p_b64_id_secret);
                
                }


    var credentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", C_GBQ_ONLINE_APP_APP_CLIENT_ID, C_GBQ_ONLINE_APP_APP_CLIENT_SECRET_ID);
    var b64_id_secret = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));

    string l_auth_code = "xxxxx"; // worked out successfully earlier  
    
    l_json_returned = getAccessToken(p_b64_id_secret, l_auth_code, C_GBQ_ONLINE_APP_REDIRECT_URL);
```

the returned json is

```
l_json_returned = : {
  "access_token": "FFFFFFFF",
  "expires_in": 3569,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Comment: Any reason your not using the Google api .net client library?

Comment: Which type of client did you create in Google Developer console?  add offline to your scopes.

Comment: i was trying to do without the library for now, may use it if i cant get this to work. what is the offline scope as i cant see it in any docs. thanks

Comment: It’s a web application

Comment: this might help https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/